# Amazon Simple Notification for unity is not working

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, notifications

I followed this instruction:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/sns.html
But when I play the example scene on Unity, this error appeared:

```
XmlException: expected '>' (3E) but found '<' (3C)  Line 3, position 6.
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Expect (Int32 expected)
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadStartTag ()
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadContent ()
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read ()
System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read ()
Mono.Xml.XmlFilterReader.Read ()
Mono.Xml.XmlFilterReader.Read ()
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ReadContent (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.IO.TextReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.IO.TextReader reader)
Amazon.AWSConfigs+<>c__DisplayClass89_0.<LoadConfigFromResource>b__0 ()
Amazon.AWSConfigs.LoadConfigFromResource ()
Amazon.AWSConfigs.GetSection[AWSSection] (System.String sectionName)
Amazon.Util.Internal.RootConfig..ctor ()
Amazon.AWSConfigs..cctor ()
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Amazon.AWSConfigs
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.Logger.ConfigureLoggers ()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.Logger..ctor (System.Type type)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.Logger.GetLogger (System.Type type)
Amazon.Util.Internal.AmazonHookedPlatformInfo..cctor ()
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Amazon.Util.Internal.AmazonHookedPlatformInfo
Amazon.UnityInitializer.Awake ()
UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent()
Amazon.UnityInitializer:AttachToGameObject(GameObject)
AWSSDK.Examples.SNSExample:Start() (at Assets/Examples/SNSExample.cs:66)
```

I also have tested on device and it did not work at all (could not found any Application Endpoint on SNS Console). I have seen many people who have same errors with me on forums, blog, etc but it seems no one found the solution.

Please help me solve this, or show me an example (which worked) of how to use Amazon Simple Notification Service on Unity.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a Sample here using Amazon Simple Notification Service on Unity:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-unity-samples/tree/master/SNS